# How to display PHP echo's in different div elements in an Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
if ($_POST['username']==""){
 echo "enter your username"; //echo 1
}
if ($_POST['password']==""){
 echo "enter your password"; //echo 2
}


 <div class="username-error"> <!-- echo 1 has to be displayed here --></div>
    <div class="password-error"> <!-- echo 2 has to be displayed here --> </div>
```

---

```
    $.ajax({
              url: $url,
              type: $type,
              data :formData,
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function(response){
                $('.username-error').html(response);
                $('.password-error').html(response);
              }
            });
```

If I want to display this two echo's separately in two div elements in another page through **ajax**, how would i do it? below are the two div's that i want them to be displayed separately.

Comment: Replace `echo` with variables. `$user = 'enter your username; $pass = 'enter your password';` Then `echo $user .'|'. $pass;`. Next in your javascript: `var splitResult = ajaxResult.split('|');` and finally put each in their own divs: `document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = splitResult[0];` and `document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = splitResult[1];`

Comment: @icecub can you show this solution in my code which i have put above?

Comment: No. It's very clear as it is and you didn't provide your javascript code so it's impossible for me to give you something more clear. Hence I wrote it in a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @icecub above is my ajax thing

Comment: I've noticed. I'll work on an answer for you

Comment: Okay, thank you @icecub :)

Comment: I've updated the near-correct answer from @ShayllisAlvesdeSousa - give that a try now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to format your output in a way that your JS script might be able to read it.

MyPHP.php

```
$usernameError = "" ;
$passwordError = ""; 

if ($_POST['username']==""){
   $usernameError = "enter your username";
}
if ($_POST['password']==""){
   $passwordError = "enter your password";
}
echo json_encode(['usernameError' => $usernameError, 'passwordError' => $passwordError]);
```

JS (Assuming that you are using jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
    data: {username: 'Username', password: 'password'},
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function(response){
    $('.username-error').text(response.usernameError);
    $('.password-error').text(response.passwordError);
})
```

Comment: First of all, you're assuming he's using jQuery. Next you're encoding the request headers and sending them back in JSON format while the question is about returning the error messages. You're kinda asking to be flagged as `Not an answer`

Comment: What would be the output of $('.username-error').text(response.username);
  $('.password-error').text(response.password);?

Comment: @S.Simith The output of this answer would be the actual Username and Password. It's not an answer to your question at all. I'm sure Shayllis ment well, but this won't help you.

Comment: @S.Simith I've modified this answer slightly as it was very close to exactly what you need.  Give this a try.

Comment: "$('.username-error').text" it puts the returned username to your div ".username-error".
And yes, it actually is an answer, just fancy and just as your request should be. Note that dataType doesn't format request data to JSON, just says to jQuery that the response is gonna be a JSON.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It is an answer now, yes. That's why I upvoted it. But it wasnt an answer before. You were returning the Username and Password. Not the error messages as was the question. Archer fixed that for you and that made it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several ways to solve your problem. I will show you 2 possible solutions. Which one you choose is up to you.

**First solution:**

Change your PHP code to this:

```
if ($_POST['username']==""){
    $userErrMsg = "enter your username"; //echo 1
}
if ($_POST['password']==""){
    $passErrMsg = "enter your password"; //echo 2
}

echo $userErrMsg .'|'. $passErrMsg;

?>
```

Next, change your jQuery ajax function to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    type: json,
    data :formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response){
        var splitResponse = response.split('|');
        $('.username-error').html(splitResponse[0]);
        $('.password-error').html(splitResponse[1]);
    }
});
```

In this solution you are returning both strings in a single string. In javascript, you are splitting that string up using the pipe character that was added in PHP. That way you have both strings available to you in javascript and you can add each to their own div element.

There are a few downsides to this solution. It assumes those error messages will be returned. If no error is returned, this solution will cause problems.

**Second solution:**

Change your PHP code to this:

```
$userErrMsg = '';
$passErrMsg = '';

if ($_POST['username']==""){
    $userErrMsg = "enter your username"; //echo 1
}
if ($_POST['password']==""){
    $passErrMsg = "enter your password"; //echo 2
}

echo json_encode(['userErrMsg' => $userErrMsg, 'passErrMsg' => $passErrMsg]);

?>
```

Next, change your jQuery ajax function to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    type: $type,
    data :formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response){
        $('.username-error').html(response.userErrMsg);
        $('.password-error').html(response.passErrMsg);
    }
});
```

In this solution you are returning both strings encoded in JSON. In javascript, you can easily access the JSON string and get the information you need out of it. The advantage of this solution is that you don't *have* to use it. You can further enhance the JSON encoded string in PHP and return success messages just as well. So your Ajax function won't get into trouble if no errors are returned.

**Last note:**
Shayllis Alves de Sousa came up with this solution before I did. Therefor you should accept his answer and not mine. I simply provided you with my answer because it makes it easier for you to work with your code.

Comment: @S.Simith That's not telling me much. Can you open your Browser console and tell me which error it displays?

Comment: That is working fine with no errors. but the problem is, when i put **response.passErrMsg** it will not display anything. but when i put only *response*, it will displaying. but both

Comment: @S.Simith Yes, I forgot to change the return type to JSON. If you copy the Ajax code from solution 2, it should work now.

Comment: I changed the type to json. but the output is nothing.

Comment: when i just put **json** the out put is nothing, and when i put **'json'**, the output is **Isset error**

Comment: @S.Simith I'm afraid I can't help you much further. The only solution from this point would be for me to use TeamViewer and login on your computer to see for myself what's going on.

Comment: I have added **dataType:''json** along with **type:$type**. So it works as expected. but there is a bug coming there. the bug is when i enter the **username** and **passowrd**, and clicked submit, the output is showing the username and password. what to do that? I want then to be not display anything, if the user clicked submit with data in both fields

Comment: @S.Simith As I said: There's not much more I can do. All I'm doing is just guessing because I don't actually see your code.

Comment: Actually your code is simple which i could understand. so i would accept your answer. and thank you everyone for giving me solutions for this. really appreciated

Comment: @S.Simith Still he came up with the solution first. It's not my intention to steal anyone's answer. I appreciate the thought but you rly should accept his :)

Comment: Okay then @icecub. Then as your wish, I accept his answer then. but you did a nice job anyway :).